# How can I convert unicode entities like this "\u2764" in valid html entities

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I am working with the twitter API and sometimes i found this characters: Today's gonna be so fun "❤" and some others like a tennis ball, a jar of beer, etc. Please see this image.

[image]

How can I take those characters and properly encoding them in a mysql database?

Comment: That's just a UNICODE character that should be handled by UTF-8.

Comment: you see this: I hate my hair after the beach  @allisimpson i mean that kind of characters, twitter accepts them but i dont know how to show them properly once i pull them from twitter api

Comment: You might be having trouble with UTF-8 characters that are more than three bytes long, as all emoji characters are.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I could sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

As usual there was something stupid :| I just added this header to the page header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); and everything worked fine.